# No puedo detener mi depurador Visual Studio 2017 en los breakpoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, aspx

Necesito configurar nuevamente mi Visual Studio 2017 para que se detenga en los breackpoint que le estoy colocando, ya que al compilar se los brinca, como si no existiern pero si estan marcados, estoy compilando mi website

Comment: Asegúrate de que estés en debug y no en release.

Comment: cuando ejecutas desde el VS los breakpoint no se llenan, o quizas no se detiene porque no pasa por alli la ejecucion

Comment: que tipo de web site se trata? es un Web Application o un Web Site, porque si el sitio no compila a dll por lo general hay problema

Comment: Es un website, no hay release

Comment: Es un website, no hay release, ya encontre como se detiene en los breakpoint pero me marca un error, ya con eso me conformo grcaias muchachos por su tiempo, cuando gane un poquito mas donare para la causa, mientras necesito aprender un poco mas

Comment: Por favor tómate un minuto para publicar como lo solucionaste en respuestas, tu aprendizaje nos servirá a otros. Gracias